# Proving a function in bounded on a subinterval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map such that $k(x):=0$ if $x=0$ and if $x \in [0,1]$ is irrational and $k(x):=n$ if $x \in [0,1]$ with $x = m/n$ for some coprime integers $m,n$.  Show that $k$ is not bounded on any subinterval $[c,d]$ with $0 \leq c < d \leq 1$.

I am not sure how to show this.  My first thought is to proceed by contradiction but I am unsure of how assuming the function is bounded is helpful.

Comment: This is the well known popcorn function. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popcorn_function or http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-continuous-at-all-irrationals-and-discontinuous-at-all-rationals/

Comment: Is there a prime larger than $\frac 1 {d - c}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that given any positive $B$, there is a fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ in lowest terms between $c$ and $d$ such that $n\gt B$.

Let $n$ be a **power of** $2$ which is larger than $B$ and has the property that $\frac{1}{n}\lt \frac{d-c}{4}$. Then there are two consecutive integers $l$ and $l+1$ such that both $\frac{l}{n}$ and $\frac{l+1}{n}$ are between $c$ and $d$. One of $l$ or $l+1$ is odd. Call it $m$. Then $\frac{m}{n}$ is in lowest terms, between $c$ and $d$, and $k(m/n)=n\gt B$.

Comment: Excellent answer! +1

Comment: Would have been my answer if it wasn't already here. Nitpick;In the Q:... m,n should be positive.

Comment: Here $n$ is automatically positive, since it is a power of $2$.